# Identifying and counting elements of the same value in an array Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I would like to count the numbers of "c" inside my array txt. The transition for 1 to 0 means a new cycle, thats why i put a "c" whenever this happen. In this code I get type mismatch when i try to count the "c". Thank you for the help.

```
Sub CopyColumn()
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Variant
ReDim arrayciclos(0)
Dim str As String
Dim ciclos As Variant

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To finalrow
 arrayciclos(UBound(arrayciclos)) = Range("J" & i)
 ReDim Preserve arrayciclos(UBound(arrayciclos) + 1)
Next i


For i = LBound(arrayciclos) To UBound(arrayciclos)
    txt = txt & arrayciclos(i) ' & vbCrLf
  Next i

  MsgBox txt


Do While InStr(txt, "10")
    txt = Replace(txt, "10", "c")
    Loop
MsgBox txt


ciclos = 0: i = 0
For i = 0 To finalrow
    If txt(i) = "c" Then ' i have Type Mismatch here
        ciclos = ciclos + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox (ciclos)


End Sub
```

Comment: I don't check the code, but **txt** it's not an array, you cannot write **txt(i)** ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your posted code, the `txt` variable is not explicitly declared. In addition, the implicit declaration of variant becomes a type of string when you use the second loop to concatenate the values together with `txt = txt & arrayciclos(I)`. You should modify the code to include the `Option Explicit` statement to check for undeclared variables. In addition you should use the `Mid` function to perform the checks for the "c" character in your final loop.

```
Option Explicit   ' <-- added to check for undeclared variables

Sub CopyColumn()
Dim finalrow As Long
Dim i As Variant
ReDim arrayciclos(0)
Dim str As String   ' <-- unused variable problaby should have been named txt in your example
Dim ciclos As Variant

finalrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
finalrow = 9
For i = 2 To finalrow
 arrayciclos(UBound(arrayciclos)) = Range("J" & i)
 ReDim Preserve arrayciclos(UBound(arrayciclos) + 1)
Next i


For i = LBound(arrayciclos) To UBound(arrayciclos)
    str = str & arrayciclos(i) ' & vbCrLf
  Next i

  MsgBox str


Do While InStr(str, "10")
    str = Replace(str, "10", "c")
    Loop
MsgBox str


ciclos = 0: i = 0
For i = 0 To finalrow
    If Mid(str, i + 1, 1) = "c" Then ' <-- changed to Mid(string, start, len)
        ciclos = ciclos + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox (ciclos)


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using too many loops. If you want to loop through the array txt To count the number of "c"  then you only need to do

```
        Dim MyArray As Variant
        dim count as integer
        'specify your range. For example
        MyArray = Range("BS27:DS50000")

        'Loop through and find all occurrences of "c"
        For i = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
          For j = LBound(MyArray, 2) To UBound(MyArray, 2)
             If MyArray(i, j) = "c" Then count = count + 1
          Next j
        Next i

        msgbox count
```

If "c" is not single within each cell then replace If MyArray(i, j) = "c" with If MyArray(i, j) = "c" and put asterix within both sides of "c" like asterix c asterix. This will be a character match

Comment: Thank you. It is a better way of doing it.